# Is there some way to automate connections to nREPL from Vim Fireplace?

Tags: vim, clojure, nrepl

I'm running `lein repl` in a project, and it successfully starts up and creates the file target/repl-port.

Using VIM version 7.4.86 I can use a command like:

`:Connect nrepl://localhost:57644`

Vim then successfully connects to the repl, and all is good.

However, my understanding is that vim-fireplace is able to make this connection all by itself using the target/repl-port file. That is not happening. I did see a comment about lein 2.3 changing to use target/repl/repl-port (I use lein 2.0.0 for this project - a requirement that is out of my control) so I tried to creating a symlink at this location, but that isn't picked up either.

I'm using the version of vim-fireplace from:
`github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace`

at the latest commit, which is currently:

```
f1b8096b3fe00cd9594c8a2bf0819efc154e9843
(Date:   Wed Oct 23 21:25:53 2013 -0700)
```

I'm hoping to automate this connection. I'm not big on VIMscript, so I was hoping that there might be some way to track down the issue without having to delve into the sources.

Comment: stupid but necessary question: is VIM's working directory inside of the appropriate lein project directory?

Comment: I should have said, sorry. Yes, it is. I'm in the directory where project.clj is. This is also the working directory of the shell where I run "lein repl".

Comment: So, you tried fireplace's issue tracker but it didn't help so you come here, right?

Comment: What sort of error do you get?

Comment: No error, just no connection. If I try a symbol lookup then it says: "Error running Clojure: Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main". But I `cat target/repl-port` and use that number to say: ":Connect nrepl://localhost:56013", then try a symbol lookup again, and it works just fine. Both "lein repl" and vim are being run in the project directory.

Comment: I should say... the project has source paths more like Maven's than the standard Leiningen layout. ie. src/main/clojure/... But Leiningen is fine being configured this way, and everything works, except for the autoconnect for fireplace.

Answer (score 1):

struggled a little bit with that too.

1. Start lein repl in your project directory
2. Start vim any-clojure-file.clj also  in your project directory

Then it should connect automatically.

Fireplace only connects automatically, when you open a clojure file.

best regards

adrian

Comment: This is what I was doing already. The question is because it doesn't connect, despite following these steps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to handle this "nowadays" is with [vim-leiningen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-leiningen).  `:Console` will connect to a REPL if there already is one running and will start one if there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I too was annoyed by this and also didn't want to learn to write vim script just for this. You can work around it with your shell:

```sh
$ alias rvim="gvim $1 +\":FireplaceConnect nrepl://localhost:`cat .nrepl-port`\""
$ rvim src/something.clj
```